# Append javascript auto-generated file to POST form and process it on PHP in $_FILES

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I'm trying to append file to a form and send it via POST request.

The problem is the file generates in js script (it's cropped image in base64)
Next, I convert it from base64 to blob. And there no idea how to link this blob to my form.

I can do it via **ajax**, but looking for way to send image as file without xhr/ajax and proccess it of PHP side in `$_FILES`.

Don't even know is it possible

My form has **attr** `'multipart/form-data'`

Comment: Maybe you could put the blob in the `.value` of a hidden input. It won't go into `$_FILES`, it will be in `$_POST`.

Comment: I can put it in a hidden field and convert on php side, yes. 
Im trying to create widget for framework and it would be easier for users to get file and continue work instead of converting it at first. Sure if i will not find any solution will use way without $_FILES

Answer (score 0):

you can create a hidden canvas and in that canvas you can draw the image with your base64 encoded string. Something like below

```
<canvas style="height:200px;width:200px;display:none;" id="picture"></canvas>
<input type="hidden" name="clicked_image" id="clicked_image" />
```

and then the javascript code as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var videoPicture = 'your base64 string';
var hiddenPictureField = document.querySelector('input#clicked_image');
var canvasPicture = window.canvas = document.querySelector('canvas#picture');
canvasPicture.width = 480;
canvasPicture.height = 360;
canvasPicture.getContext('2d').
drawImage(videoPicture, 0, 0, canvasPicture.width, canvasPicture.height);
hiddenPictureField.value = canvasPicture.toDataURL("image/png");
</script>
```

And then you will get the image in the clicked_image field. The base 64 string you can process it accordingly.

Comment: Couldn't he just do `hiddenPictureField.value = 'your base64 string';` and skip the canvas stuff?

Comment: But clicked_image is text type always ? It will be sent as text data, when i need it to send as file like in type="file".

Comment: yes you can do that way also and there is no way you can set the contents of a file, it is only the text field that you can make and directly, show that to your user. I used the canvas only in case you need to show that to your frontend user, you just can change its style.

You cannot set the value of blob to input type file, instead you need to set the value of text field with your base64 string and at the receiving end process it accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @user3428885 What difference does it make if you send it as text or file? Either way you can write it to a server file in PHP.

Comment: This is part of my input widget for yii2 framework, it's affect only on a input element but not on the form. So, i would create all work on client side and let users use _FILES on a server side if it possible

Comment: @user3428885 As per my knowledge, No dynamically writing to _FILES is not possible unless you have a path for the file or a file in your temp.